# How to set a variable to default value?

Tags: bash, shell

The following code is working as expected to check the user input.

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
myvar='80'
else
myvar="$1"
fi
```

But I had read a very short syntax that will do the same. Any pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
myvar=${1:-"80"}
```

Comment: # I had figured it out to be something like this... myvar=${1:-80} # but I guess the quotes are necessary. Or are they really?